# In defense of consequentalism

Tags: logic, ethics

Deontologists such as Thomas Nagel say Consequentialism permits actions that aim at evil, which is why it is a false theory.

1. If a (moral) Theory permits actions that aim at evil then it is wrong.
2. Consequentialism permits actions that aim at evil.
   |- Consequentialism is wrong.

What would be a the most persuasive counter argument?

Comment: I think there is a basic language problem here that prevents any real answer.  Ignore the specific chosen systems.  Two ethics differ by allowing different things.  So if the word 'evil' is interpreted in the speaker's ethics then 2 dismisses all other ethical systems as wrong, which is clearly just prejudicial nonsense.  If it is interpreted in the holder's ethics, then the conditions of 1 are never true: A system may consider permitted actions 'evil', in some contingent or relative manner.  But none will permit pursuing aims that it considers, in themselves, to be evil.

Answer (score 3):

The syllogism is [question-begging](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/begging-the-question.html).  What does it mean for an action to be "aimed at evil" if 'evil' is defined in consequentialist terms?  If evil exists before the consequences of an action are known, it can only be that we assuming a non-consequentialist moral framework, i.e. exactly what Nagel is seeking to prove.  Thus, Nagel is assuming into his syllogism the outcome that he purports the syllogism to prove.

Comment: Dialectic is not contradiction or begging the question.  Every consequentialist still has a definition of evil (if only one that shifts continually), and every deontology still has an expected outcome (if only a metaphysical one).  That does not mean that they are pointless or baseless concepts.

Answer (score 0):

There's only a couple ways to go about this:

1. Deny 1 and say that a moral theory can permit evil and still be right. This is kinda hard to do, if you ask me, but might be tempting for something like Virtue Theorists to say (e.g. a virtuous person needn't *always* do the right thing, they should just be a good person most of the time). If you're coming at this as a Consequentialist, however, it might be better to leave 1 alone.
2. You can dig in your heels and deny that Consequentialism permits evil actions. After all, consequentialism *does* provide a criterion for moral rightness - it's just that deontologists (or whatever) feel at odds with what it labels moral and immoral. However, butting heads over moral criteria is just frustrating for both parties, and I don't advise it.

At that point, you can either argue that deontology is wrong by its very nature, or that it's actually the same thing as consequentialism. A great example is "Should I lie to protect innocent people from Nazis despite the supposed moral fact saying that it's wrong to lie?" Sometimes deontology veers dangerously close to absolutism, which is something you can and should hammer them for because it's really hard to defend.

Modern deontologists often see the need to back up deontology with other philosophical doo-dads that make it weaker in the end. Frances Kamm's "Principle of Permissible Harm" is a good example - it essentially adds in a consequentialist element to deontology which kinda defeats the point of having this discussion.

Even without this, you can also hammer deontologists on why a certain thing is wrong. Ask them why it's wrong to kill puppies, for instance. They'll give you a long answer relating to something Kant said, but if you iterate and ask why we have a duty to do X or how our intentions have to be in the right place, a lot of people will eventually say, "Look, it's just wrong! It hurts the puppy and that's bad!" At that point, you've got them pinned.